# Unable to display database items by todays date plus 7 days

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to MySQL and trying to display items from my database using items that have a date from today plus the next days days (like a calendar) and it's only showing items after 7 days.

An example of the output is;

2022-12-28 11:02:00 (Showing after todays date plus the next 7 days)

My code is;

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM reminders_sc WHERE reminder_date > CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY");
```

I also tried;

```
$now = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM care_plan_review where reminder_date > ? order by id desc');
$stmt->execute([$now]);
```

This just showed everything in the database :(

Database is colunm datetime format.

I have looked on SO and can't figure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: "it's only showing items after 7 days" - what does that mean? Can you share sample input that should, and others that should not be shown?

Comment: The query selects all items with a reminder date that is at least seven days in the future - what else do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want "greater than", you want to use "between". The `>` (greater than) means the date must be beyond 7 days. Using `between` you can check that the date is between `now` (today) and 7 days.

```
reminder_date between now() and now() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Additional note:

```
Y-m-d h:i:sa
```

would not give you a MySQL datetime value. You'd want `Y-m-d H:i:s`. Also if your PHP and MySQL have different timezone settings this can result in different data returns.

Comment: Awesome - thank you so much - works perfectly and can see where I was going wrong.